# ASP.NET - Get User ID For Seeding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing a code-first database and I was wondering how I can get the ID for the seeded users that I have stored.

In this part of the code, I am creating the users.

```
         //Users
        List<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>();
        applicationUsers.Add(new ApplicationUser() { Email = "person1@test.test", UserName = "person1@test.test" });
        applicationUsers.Add(new ApplicationUser() { Email = "person2@test.test", UserName = "person2@test.test" });
        applicationUsers.Add(new ApplicationUser() { Email = "person3@test.test", UserName = "person3@test.test" });
        applicationUsers.Add(new ApplicationUser() { Email = "person4@test.test", UserName = "person4@test.test" });
        applicationUsers.Add(new ApplicationUser() { Email = "person5@test.test", UserName = "person5@test.test" });

        foreach (ApplicationUser user in applicationUsers)
        {
            manager2.Create(user, "qweQWE123!@#");
            manager2.AddToRole(user.Id, "RegisteredUser");
        }
```

And that works well, the users are in my database, however, I have a model which uses the UserID as a foreign key. How would I get the GUID Generated from creating these users within the seeded method?
This is the model of the item model, the one which uses a User ID Foreign key.

```
        [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser applicationUser { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ItemTypeID { get; set; }
    public ItemTypeModels ItemTypemodels { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Quantity can't be negative")]
    public int ItemQuantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int QualityID { get; set; }
    public QualityModels Qualitymodels { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Price must be over 0")]
    public double ItemPrice { get; set; }

}
```

This is how I fill in the item

```
itemList.Add(new ItemModels() { ItemTypeID = 1, ItemPrice = 1.67,  ItemQuantity = 1, QualityID = 1, UserId="What do i put here?" });
```

Comment: Doesn't `UserManager.Create` return the created user? You should be able to get the info from there

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 UserManager.Create returns IdentityResult which only contains a boolean value if the create succeeded or not.

Comment: You're right, Create populates the Id property in the user passed to it (you use it on the next line)... So why can't you just use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop you're already accessing the user.Id property in `manager2.AddToRole()`.

The easiest way to seed your `item` is create the item object inside that loop then save after adding all the items.

```
var itemList = new List<ItemModels>();

foreach (ApplicationUser user in applicationUsers)
{
   manager2.Create(user, "qweQWE123!@#");
   manager2.AddToRole(user.Id, "RegisteredUser");

   // use user.Id for ItemModel then add to list
   itemList.Add(new ItemModels() { UserId = user.Id, ItemTypeID = 1, ItemPrice = 1.67,  ItemQuantity = 1, QualityID = 1 });

}

// then save your items here
context.Items.AddToRange(itemList);
context.SaveChanges();
```